# Cucumber - perform ActiveJob `perform_later` jobs immediately

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I have many jobs that are calling other nested jobs using `perform_later`. However, during some tests on Cucumber, I'd like to execute those jobs immediately after to proceed with the rests of the tests.

I thought it would be enough to add

```
# features/support/active_job.rb
World(ActiveJob::TestHelper)
```

And to call jobs using this in a step definition file

```
perform_enqueued_jobs do
  # call step that calls MyJob.perform_later(*args)
end
```

However I run into something like that

```
undefined method `perform_enqueued_jobs' for #<ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter:0x007f98fd03b900> (NoMethodError)
```

What am I missing / doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you found the answer to this? I'm running into the same problem right now.

Comment: Hey @Rystraum I'm looking at my working code right now, and apparently my tests are using `.perform_now` in the steps and it seems to work fine. I don't believe I had to modify hidden settings anywhere... see my answer

Answer (score 1):

I switched to the :test adapter in tests and it worked out for me:

```
# initialisers/test.rb

config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test

# features/support/env.rb

World(ActiveJob::TestHelper)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem as long as you call `.perform_now` inside the cucumber step, even if there are nested jobs with `.deliver_later` inside, it does work too

```
#support/active_job.rb
World(ActiveJob::TestHelper)

#my_job_steps.rb
Given(/^my job starts$/) do
  MyJob.perform_now(logger: 'stdout')
end

#jobs/my_job.rb
...
MyNestedJob.perform_later(*args) # is triggered during the step
...
```

Also, in my `environment/test.rb` file I didn't write anything concerning ActiveJob, the default was working fine. I believe the default adapter for tests is `:inline` so calling `.deliver_later` `_now` shouldn't matter

Comment: Thanks! This is ideal if you're testing Jobs directly. I've found another way if you want to keep testing at the integration level (e.g. signing up should send out an email). I wrote it up in my blog real quick, and will post it as a separate answer when I get to polish it. Here's the link: http://rystraum.com/testing-email-deliveries-using-cucumbercapybaraminitest/

Comment: Hey thanks, it will be a nice addition, although emails are a bit of a special case. Actually my own use case involved scheduling, but since `whenever` scheduling is not easily integrable in Cucumber, I decided to write a step with what actually happens in the scheduled action, and it was simpler to launch the jobs directly in the step.